# Want to play video efficiently using textureview to resolve fatal signal N error

Tags: android, android-textureview

I am using videoView to play video but I am getting fatal signal 6 error so I got solution that use textureview instead of videoview but I have no idea how to use it .
This is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView listview;
    CustomListAdapter adapter;
    private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public static int currentItem;
    public static ArrayList<String> videoLIst;
    public static MediaController mediaController ;
    boolean pauseOnScroll = true;
    boolean pauseOnFling = true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
        System.gc();

        videoLIst = new ArrayList<String>();
         mediaController = new MediaController(MainActivity.this); 
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/experience/165/video/father-and-young-daughter.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/experience/185/video/couple-on-sail-boat.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/experience/39/video/VID-20141231-WA0006.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/experience/26/video/VID-20141216-WA0004.mp4");
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listview.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, videoLIst));
         listview.setRecyclerListener(new RecyclerListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMovedToScrapHeap(View view) {
                    VideoView videoView = (VideoView)view.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

                }
            });
      listview.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
          private int mFirstVisibleRow = -1;
          private int mActiveItem = -1;

          @Override
          public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
          }


          @Override
          public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                               int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
              int firstVisibleRow = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
              if( mFirstVisibleRow != firstVisibleRow )
              {
                  mFirstVisibleRow = firstVisibleRow;

                  // Cancel the video of the previous active item
                  VideoView prevActiveVideoView = getVideoViewForRow(mActiveItem);
                  if( prevActiveVideoView != null )
                  {
                      prevActiveVideoView.pause();
                  }

                  // Start the video of the new active item
                  mActiveItem = mFirstVisibleRow + 1;
                  VideoView newActiveVideoView = getVideoViewForRow(mActiveItem);
                  if(newActiveVideoView != null)
                  {
                      newActiveVideoView.start();

                  }
              }
          }

          private VideoView getVideoViewForRow(int row)
          {
              int firstVisibleRow = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
              View rowView = listview.getChildAt(row-firstVisibleRow);
              return (rowView == null) ? null : (VideoView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
          }

      });

    }
    static class ViewHolderItem {

                TextView textViewItem;
                VideoView video;
                ProgressBar progressbar;
            }

    public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Activity activity;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private ArrayList<String> videoList;

        public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> videoList) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.videoList = videoList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return videoList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int location) {
            return videoList.get(location);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


             final ViewHolderItem viewHolder;


             if (convertView == null){
                  inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                  convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_list_item, null);

                   viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
                   viewHolder.video = (VideoView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
                   viewHolder.progressbar = (ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress);

                   viewHolder.textViewItem =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txvposition);


                   int pos;
                   pos=viewHolder.video.getCurrentPosition();
                   Log.d("current item position:",""+pos);
                    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

             }else{
                viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();

             }

             viewHolder.textViewItem.setText("Video"+position);
//             mediaController.setAnchorView(viewHolder.video);
             Log.d("video url inadapter:", ""+videoLIst.toString());
             Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoList.get(position));
            // viewHolder.video.setMediaController(mediaController);
           //  viewHolder.video.setVideoURI(uri);
             new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     viewHolder.video.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     viewHolder.video.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     viewHolder.video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoList.get(position)));
                }
            }, 200);
             //viewHolder.video.start();
             viewHolder.video.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                     public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                           viewHolder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                           viewHolder.video.start();
                           viewHolder.video.setBackgroundResource(0);

                     }
                   });
             viewHolder.video.setOnInfoListener(new OnInfoListener() {
                      @Override
                       public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         Log.d("BUFFRRING START", "On_InFO");
                         if (MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START == what) {
                               viewHolder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                             Log.d("BUFFRRING START", "" + what);
                         }
                         if (MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END == what) {
                               viewHolder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                               Log.d("BUFFRRING END", "" + what);
                         }
                         if (MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START == what) {
                               viewHolder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                               Log.d("RENDERING END", "" + what);
                         }
                         return false;
                       }
                   });
              viewHolder.video.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

                       @Override
                       public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                           Log.d("Error", "------>error" + what + "/" + extra);
                           if (extra != 0) {
                               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Can't Play Video",
                                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           }

                           return false;
                       }
                   });
              viewHolder.video.clearAnimation();
              return convertView;           
        }

    }

}
```

activity_view.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

video_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/VideoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />
 <ProgressBar 
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txvposition"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am facing this two proble.
1)On scroll videos/list items starts buffering again for the item that was already buffered.
2)On fast scroll list gets too laggy and get stuck and crashes.

please give me guidence how I used textureview insted of videoview.

Comment: have you got any solution to your problem ?